# White space on the bottom of html page

Tags: html, css

When I made my HTNL page, it looked perfect, but all of a sudden, I've been getting this huge white space on the bottom of my page. you can see it at http://thomaswd.com/pearinc2. How do I get rid of this?! My stylesheet's at http://thomaswd.com/pearinc2/style.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the HTML element with the class `back-iphone4s` you'll notice it's positioned relatively using CSS.

If you remove the `position: relative` portion from the CSS rules for `.back-iphone4s` you'll notice it appears where your white space is.

Using `position: relative` like this is always horrible, white space appears where the element *would* have been if it wasn't positioned relatively.

What I would recommend is adding `position: relative` to the div with `devices` as its class, then use `position: absolute;` on `.back-iphone4s` and set it's position using that method. This way the `back-iphone4s` element is positioned relatively to it's parent, not relatively to where it would be in the normal document flow.

There are are a number of other ways you could solve this too, at I glance I would be very tempted to just turn those two iphones into one image, less HTML, less CSS and less images to download, but it appears you may have inteneded them to be seperate for a purpose, so maybe that's not a viable solution.

... phew, hope that makes sense, let me know if now.

Comment: umm...It doesn't work. I tried using position:absolute and the white space was still there

Comment: I posted the newer version no that same url, please take a look at it

Comment: did you put `position: relative;` on the `devices` div?

Comment: When I do that using firebug on my end it works perfectly, can you update the link you posted with the css you've tried? Then I can see where you've gone wrong

Comment: in your ammended HTML/CSS you've added a section div at the bottom with a height of 520px ... this is what is now causing the whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

#### Give a `height` to the `.devices` class:

```
.devices {height: 520px;}
```

---

[image]

Comment: Or try this: `.devices {height: 520px !important;}`

Answer (score 0):

I just had a quick look at your style, what I saw is technically very ugly.
You set all main elements with position:absolute and made them independent from context and content-flow. And because they are absolute, you have to give them a height - and that causes in things like that ugly white-space.
I would say you have the wrong concept of styling / structuring the page.

Try to use "position:absolute" very rare!

Comment: I cant get the content to be full width without position:absolute

Comment: What do mean by 'full width'? It's easy to get content to cover the width of the page without using `position: absolute` just use percentage widths e.g. `.example { width: 100%; }`